# How to map @RequestBody to Java Object implementing Builder Pattern

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, builder

I am using a domain object imported from other service which implements builder pattern and hence have no No-arg Constructor and setters. I want to map JSON coming from @RequestBody to this domain object. I know I can annotate it with @JSONPojoBuilder and some other ones but i don't have control over it. So I'm stuck with writing my own JSON to Object mapper which i don't think is a good idea as it involves validations etc. and is tightly coupled with request body.

Code -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "someurl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<ObjectA> addObject(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody @NonNull String body) {
    ObjectA obj = service.addObject(id, mapper.mapJSONToObject(body));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(obj , HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Instead of writing my own mapper, I heard we can use some message convertor and pass our Builder class as some argument. I did not find such examples, if anybody has done it before or can point me to some site, that'd be helpful.

Comment: You might be looking for _Jackson mixins_.

Comment: Jackson Mixins means annotations at object, i don't want annotations in my object.

Comment: Jackson mixins _specifically_ mean that _you don't modify the original object_; that's the entire point.

Comment: Okay, Got your point, but that'll introduce too many mixin objects and again gets tightly coupled with annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never tried that, but in general Spring MVC supports the abstraction of "Custom Converters" that you can write in order to help spring to convert JSON to complicated objects.

I assume that you have a `MyComplicatedClass` without no-ops constructor but with a builder.
So you can do the following:

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

@Component // note the converter is also a spring bean so you can, say, inject object mapper and convert to JsonNode-s for example (see below) 
public class MyComplicatedClassConverter implements Converter<String, MyComplicatedClass> {
     @Autowired // or use constructor injection
     private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    /**
     * Override the convert method
     * @param object in a string representation to be converted
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public MyComplicatedClass convert(String object) {
       JsonNode node=  objectMapper.readTree(/*byte array input stream from object string or something */);
        
        return MyComplicatedClass.builder()
                                  .withSomeProperty(node.get("someProperty").textValue()
                                  .withAnotherProperty(node.get("anotherProperty").intValue()
                                  .build();
    }

}
```

Now, when your application recognizes this converter it allows using `MyComplicatedClass`  in the controller's methods as if spring knows how to convert it.
So the code snippet that you've presented in your example should work.

All this is done without "touching" the code of `MyComplicatedClass`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark, It worked. At least it's way better than the mapper I'm writing. Few pointers tho - 
1. getString is not a method unfortunately so I needed to use get().asText() a lot which led me to check for nulls a lot.
2. It's tightly coupled with the names of keys. I was hoping there would be some way to map those automatically to "with...." methods.

Anyway, It worked fine and reduced lot of my code which reduced lots of testing :P 
I'll mark it as accepted answer if you edit some parts of your answer

Comment: Yeah, I haven't checked the exact api of json node, anyway, I've updated the answer for the sake of completeness of the answer. Thanks!